# How to make a wind force field, does not affect all objects in front of it (cloth simulation)?

Tags: cloth-simulation, force-fields

How to make a wind force field, to affect on some objects but does not affect on the others?

In my case, I want the wind affect on clothes, hanging on the rope, but did not affect on the rope (the rope - cloth simulation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cloth enabled object has a "cloth field weights" panel where you can set the influence for several dynamic effects, separately: one is wind, try set it to zero for "wind".

[image]